# How does the stack overflow save all the questions and answers ? Whether they save it in DB or file?

Tags: xml, database

How does the stack overflow save all the questions and answers ? 
Whether they save it in DB or file ?

What is a better way to save a large amount of searchable data ?

Comment: SO uses databases, yes. [Databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) (there are many kinds) are often great ways to organize and store "searchable data". Many databases (remember, there are many different kinds!) offer various methods to speed up searches by allowing indexing.

Comment: u mean questions and answers are both saved in DB ?

Comment: Of course. Would you want 21721707 (or more) separate files? That seems like a nightmare!